# Place a button right aligned

Tags: html, css

I use this code to right align a button.

```html
<p align="right">
  <input type="button" value="Click Me" />
</p>
```

But `<p>` tags wastes some space, so looking to do the same with `<span>` or `<div>`.

Comment: The `align` attribute is deprecated in HTML 4.01 and unsupported in HTML5, use CSS `text-align` instead to achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 573, accepted):

Which alignment technique you use depends on your circumstances but the basic one is `float: right;`:

```
<input type="button" value="Click Me" style="float: right;">
```

You'll probably want to clear your floats though but that can be done with `overflow:hidden` on the parent container or an explicit `<div style="clear: both;"></div>` at the bottom of the container.

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/8UvVg/

Floated elements are removed from the normal document flow so they can overflow their parent's boundary and mess up the parent's height, the [`clear:both`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#flow-control) CSS takes care of that (as does `overflow:hidden`). Play around with the JSFiddle example I added to see how floating and clearing behave (you'll want to drop the `overflow:hidden` first though).

Answer (score 84):

## If the button is the only `element` on the `block`:

```css
.border {
  border: 2px blue dashed;
}

.mr-0 {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.ml-auto {
  margin-left:auto;
}
.d-block {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<p class="border">
  <input type="button" class="d-block mr-0 ml-auto" value="The Button">
</p>
```

## If there are **other** `elements` on the `block`:

```css
.border {
  border: 2px indigo dashed;
}

.d-table {
  display:table;
}

.d-table-cell {
  display:table-cell;
}

.w-100 {
  width: 100%;
}

.tar {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="border d-table w-100">
  <p class="d-table-cell">The paragraph.....lorem ipsum...etc.</p>
  <div class="d-table-cell tar">
    <button >The Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

## With `flex-box`:

```css
.flex-box {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  outline: 2px dashed blue;
}

.flex-box-2 {
  display:flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  outline: 2px deeppink dashed;
}
```

```html
<h1>Button with Text</h1>
<div class="flex-box">
<p>Once upon a time in a ...</p>
<button>Read More...</button>
</div>

<h1>Only Button</h1>
<div class="flex-box-2">
  <button>The Button</button>
</div>

<h1>Multiple Buttons</h1>
<div class="flex-box-2">
  <button>Button 1</button>
  <button>Button 2</button>
</div>
```

Good Luck...

Comment: The `margin-left:auto` is great! The `!important` is the worst, it'll cause problems in the future.

Comment: Hi @TomBrito, I've updated the answer with `display: flex;`.  It takes care of everything.

Comment: this answer is better than it gets credit for... just don't use !important

Comment: Yeah, flex box is pretty awesome.

Answer (score 46):

Another possibility is to use an absolute positioning oriented to the right:

```
<input type="button" value="Click Me" style="position: absolute; right: 0;">
```

Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/a2Ld1xse/

This solution has its downsides, but there are use cases where it's very useful.

Comment: If you add position:relative to the parent element , it works fine!

Answer (score 23):

```html
<div style = "display: flex; justify-content:flex-end">
    <button>Click me!</button>
</div>
```

```
<div style = "display: flex; justify-content: flex-end">
    <button>Click me!</button>
</div>
```

Comment: A bit more context for your answer would be useful.

Answer (score 19):

a modern approach in 2019 using **flex-box**

with **div** tag

```html
<div style="display:flex; justify-content:flex-end; width:100%; padding:0;">
    <input type="button" value="Click Me"/>
</div>
```

with **span** tag

```html
<span style="display:flex; justify-content:flex-end; width:100%; padding:0;">
    <input type="button" value="Click Me"/>
</span>
```

Answer (score 12):

This solution depends on Bootstrap 3, as pointed out by @günther-jena

Try `<a class="btn text-right">Call to Action</a>`. This way you don't need extra markup or rules to clear out floated elements.

Comment: sorry correction, it only works when you put "text-right" on the parent container for the anchor tag.

Answer (score 8):

To keep the button in the page flow:

```
<input type="button" value="Click Me" style="margin-left: auto; display: block;" />
```

*(put that style in a .css file, do not use this html inline, for better maintenance)*

Answer (score 6):

Another possibility is to use an absolute positioning oriented to the right. You can do it this way:

```
style="position: absolute; right: 0;"
```

Comment: Sure, but if there's a parent `div`, this will emphatically ignore its confines.

Answer (score 6):

It is not always so simple and sometimes the alignment must be defined in the container and not in the Button element itself !

For your case, the solution would be

```
<div style="text-align:right; width:100%; padding:0;">
    <input type="button" value="Click Me"/>
</div>
```

I have taken care to specify `width=100%` to be sure that `<div>` take full width of his container.

I have also added `padding:0` to avoid before and after space as with `<p>` element.

I can say that if `<div>` is defined in a FSF/Primefaces table's footer, the `float:right` don't work correctly because the Button height will become higher than the footer height !

In this Primefaces situation, the only acceptable solution is to use `text-align:right` in container.

With this solution, if you have 6 Buttons to align at right, you must only specify this alignment in container :-)

```
<div style="text-align:right; width:100%; padding:0;">
    <input type="button" value="Click Me 1"/>
    <input type="button" value="Click Me 2"/>
    <input type="button" value="Click Me 3"/>
    <input type="button" value="Click Me 4"/>
    <input type="button" value="Click Me 5"/>
    <input type="button" value="Click Me 6"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case the

```
<p align="right"/>
```

worked fine

Comment: This is not an answer The align attribute is deprecated in HTML 4.01 and unsupported in HTML5, use CSS text-align instead to achieve the same effect

Answer (score -2):

with **float-right** bootstrap class :

```
 <button class="float-right">RIGHT</button>
```

Comment: before you say it doesn't work, please understand the answer.
it is well written with bootstrap so if you don't have bootstrap or if you have a version lower than 4 it is logical that it won't work.
please find the link to the official documentation : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/float/