# How do I align a button to the right?

Tags: html, css

How would I align a button to the right?

I've tried `text-align: right;` and `align-content: right;`

I would also like the button have `display: flex;`

```css
#hideShow {
  display: flex;
  text-align: right;
  align-content: right;
}
```

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<button class="flex" id="hideShow" onclick="hideBtTS()">Hide</button>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Place a button right aligned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6632340/place-a-button-right-aligned)

Comment: Try float : right ;

Comment: @LeoRamadani float is not a good solution

Comment: @Roy i dont think thats supported in HTML5

Answer (score 2):

You should have flex on your parent div. Also, you can try using
`{ display: flex; justify-content: flex-end; }`

`justify-content` will align your button with the end of your parent div (right side of the window).

Answer (score 0):

You can use margin-left: auto, but you have to display it as a block as follows -

```
#hideShow {
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
}
```

If you want it at centre then also add margin-right: auto as follows -

```
#hideShow {
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I am assuming that your button container is 100% width.

CSS:

```
.btn-container {
    display:flex;
    justify-content:flex-end
}
//#hideShow {
//    display: flex;
//    text-align: right;
//    align-content: right;
//}
```

HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="flex">
    <form action="../index.html" id="BtTS">
        <input type="submit" value="<--- Back to Title Screen" />
    </form>
    <div class="btn-container" align="right">
        <button class="flex" id="hideShow" onclick="hideBtTS()">Hide</button>
    </div>
    </div>
<div id="dividers">
    <hr><br><br>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[check the result here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LykJl.png)

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't work in my main code, could you take a look?

HTML:
https://pastebin.com/4HmVuZJL

CSS:
https://pastebin.com/zR6C4z1u

Comment: just add width:100% to btn-container class like this https://jsfiddle.net/bh1e6yvt/2/

Comment: however this one is more elegant solution: https://jsfiddle.net/bh1e6yvt/4/

Answer (score 0):

You are doing changes on the text inside the button.
You have to put "text-align: right" to the container not the button

```css
#right {
  text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: didn't work for me... Could you look at my code? 
https://pastebin.com/ka1cRxht

Comment: I see.. Just add "justify-content: space-between". check this out https://jsfiddle.net/cpm2v9ts/

Comment: Thank you very much but I found another way! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
.btn-container {
   justify-content: flex-end;
   position: relative;
   bottom: 38px;
}
```

Adjust `bottom: ;` to whatever you need.

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.flex{
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between!important;
}
```