# Align 2 buttons to the right of text

Tags: html, css, angular

I am trying to make my two buttons appear on the far right of a piece of text. I want the text and two buttons to all be inline with each other but the text is on the left and the two buttons are on the right. I have seen multiple solutions and I could get it to work with only 1 button but when I have two buttons it does not work.

I run a for loop over 'weaknesses' and print out each weakness. Each weakness will have an update and delete action.

I tried to do margin-left but each weakness is a different length so my buttons would not line up

I also tried using some solutions from this post but could not seem to get the expected outcome: [Place a button right aligned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6632340/place-a-button-right-aligned)

Any help would be appreciated

HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let weakness of weaknesses | async">
    <div class="flex-box">
        <p>{{ weakness }}</p>
        <a class="btn btn-light btn-sm pull-right" href="#">Update</a>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is auto margin with flex

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

nav button:first-of-type {
  /* Key here is margin-left needs to be auto */
  margin: 0 10px 0 auto
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <span>Text</span>
  <button>Button 1</button>
  <button>Button 2</button>
</nav>
```

Comment: I accidently mentioned 2 buttons but one is an <a> tag. This solution works with 2 buttons. Is there a way to make it work with 1 <a> and 1 button?

EDIT - Got it working, thank you :)

Comment: @Hg0428 true, but there's no reason for `position: fixed` (which can cause unintended issues later) or floats (which have been deprecated for some time).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```css
#btnHolder {
  position:fixed;
  top:10px;
  right:10px;
  
}
```

```html
<p>Text is here</p>
<div id="btnHolder">
    <button>Update</button>
    <button>Delete</button>
</div>
```

I dont know why it was so hard. It should have been easier to fix this problem.

Comment: From your code snippet it is not outputting the expected result. I am looking to make everything be lined up. So the text is on the left and you have the 2 buttons on the right

Comment: @Darren_D19
I can fix that in the CSS, I just didn't know you needed that.

Comment: Oh sorry, hopefully you understand what way I want now, I appreciate your help

Comment: @Darren_D19 I fixed it for you. You can add float: right or whatever else you need. If you want them on separate lines then just add a br.

Comment: The buttons now appear in the top right of the screen instead of inside where the text is. I will play around with it

Comment: @Darren_D19
It seems to work for me. It is displaying as 

|Text              Update Delete|

Comment: It must be the way I have it written. The above solution worked for me. Thank you for your help though

Answer (score 0):

You should do it like this:

```css
 .flex-box {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: start;
  }

 #buttons{
      margin-left: 10px;
  }
```

```html
  <div class="flex-box">
  <p>Text is here</p>
  <div id="buttons">
   <a>Update</a>
   <button>Delete</button>
 </div>
</div>
```